# How to delete the first word in each line of a file?

Tags: text-processing, command, cut

consider a file names 'file.txt'.
It contains the following.

```
dove is a bird
tiger is an animal
cricket is a game.
```

Expected output:

```
is a bird
is an animal
is a game.
```

Comment: Delete the first word and the trailing space...

Answer (score 19):

To do it using `cut`

```
cut -f 2- -d ' ' file.txt > new_file.txt
```

"Give me the second and any other field beyond, using space as a delimiter, from the file.txt file and direct the output to new_file.txt"

Answer (score 6):

using sed :

```
sed 's/[^ ]* //' list.txt
```

- will remove all till first space

Comment: ... and through the first space :)

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes....

Answer (score 5):

with awk:

```
awk '{ $1=""; print substr($0,2) }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

With sed

To remove the first word: `sed -E "s,^[[:alnum:]]+ ,," list.txt`

To remove the first character: `sed -E "s,^[[:alnum:]],," list.txt`

Comment: what if it has any punctuations or symbols...

Answer (score 1):

In Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/.*? //'  input
```

In Grep:

```
grep -Po ' \K.*' input
```

Answer (score 1):

[Use ed, man!](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html)

```
ed -s input <<< $'%s/^[^ ][^ ]* //\nw\nq'
```

or, with a here-string:

```
printf '%s\n' '%s/^[^ ][^ ]* //' 'w' 'q' | ed -s input
```

This sends three newline-separated commands to `ed`:

1. on every (`%`) line, `s`earch and replace one or more non-space characters and a trailing space with nothing; the search pattern is anchored to match at the beginning of the line with `^`
2. `w`rite the file back to disk
3. `q`uit

Answer (score 0):

awk is best, because it also removed preceding whitespace. And it's aliasable:

alias removefirstword="awk '{ \$1=\"\"; print substr(\$0,2) }'"

testhost: uptime

15:26:50 up 0 days, 14:42, 1 users,  load average: 1.24, 1.28, 1.33

testhost: uptime | removefirstword

up 0 days, 14:42, 1 users, load average: 1.19, 1.26, 1.32

Of course, the other regexp solutions could do this, too.

Answer (score -1):

With `bash`:

```
while read; do
  set -f -- $REPLY
  shift
  echo "$@"
done < infile
```

Output:

```
is a bird
is an animal
is a game.
```